# Show that the weak topology on $\Bbb R^n$ is the same as the standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that the weak topology on $\Bbb R^n$ is the same as the standard topology on $\Bbb R^n$.

My definition for the weak topology $\tau_{w}$ is that it's induced by the bounded linear maps from normed space $E \to \Bbb R$.

I think I need to show the inclusion both ways here. If I pick $O \in \tau_{w}$, then I suppose that $O=f^{-1}(U)$ for some bounded linear map $f$ and $U$ open in $\Bbb R$? I feel like this should be the easier direction to show, but I don't know why would it be that $O \in \tau_{std}$?

For the other direction I think I can use the fact that $\pi_i: \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ is a bounded linear map?

Comment: First, you need to show that all bounded linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous with respect to the usual topology. Hint: simply prove that all such linear maps are countinuous. This will give you that if $O \in \tau_w$, then $O \in \tau_{std}$. The harder direction is showing that if $O \in \tau_{std}$ then $O \in \tau_w$. For this, you should show that if $x \in O \in \tau_{std}$, then there is some $O' \in \tau_w$ such that $x \in O' \subseteq O$. It suffices to consider the case where $O$ is an open ball.

Comment: Why does the continuity of bounded linear maps imply that $O \in \tau_{std}$?

Comment: Because $O = f^{-1}(U)$ where $f$ is continuous and $U$ open

Comment: This is what I can follow, but why would it follow that the preimage of open set under continuous map is necessarily in $\tau_{std}$? I can see that $O$ will belong to some topology, but why $\tau_{std}$?

Comment: Because you have proved that $f$ is continuous with respect to the usual topology.

Comment: Is the standard topology defined as the product topology? Or as a certain metric topology?

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm only given $\tau_{std}$. I suppose it's the one where open balls are considered open sets. So induced by a metric(?).

Comment: @MarkSaving If I show that the bounded linear maps are continuous I've shown that $O$ is the preimage under some bounded linear map of some $U$ open in the codomain equipped with the standard topology, but how does this tell me anything about the topology on the domain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $\tau_{std}$ is the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^n$. In other words, $\tau_{std}$ is the smallest topology making all the $\pi_i$ continuous. By contrast, $\tau_w$ is the smallest topology making all the bounded linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous.

To show that $\tau_{std} \subseteq \tau_w$, it suffices to show that $\tau_w$ makes all the $\pi_i$ continuous. Because the $\pi_i$ are bounded linear maps, this is immediate.

To show that $\tau_w \subseteq \tau_{std}$, it suffices to show that $\tau_{std}$ makes all the bounded linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ continuous. In other words, for this stage of the proof, you should verify that using the normal topology, all bounded linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous. In fact, you can simply show that all linear maps $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous.

Comment: Thanks this makes sense. It's the fact that $\tau_w$ is the coarsest/smallest topology making the bounded linear maps continuous that implies $\tau_w \subseteq \tau_{std}$.

Comment: For your second proof that $\tau_{std} \subseteq \tau_w$. Is it so that since $\{ \pi_i \mid i \in \{1, \dots, n\} \} \subseteq \{f : \Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R \mid f \text{ linear} \}$ we only need to show that $\tau_w$ makes the $\pi_i$ continuous?

Comment: @Lakritsa Technically, we need to show that the $\pi_i$ are bounded linear, which means that $\tau_w$ makes them continuous. But basically yes.